# Win 7/10 64 bit -- Registering VBR/TLB files

Tags: com+, dcom, win64, clireg32

Back in the day, we used to register VBR files with CLIREG32:

```
clireg32 somefile.vbr -t somefile.tlb -s someservername -d -q -nologo
```

Has this been replaced or changed with Win 7/10 64 bit systems?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: You tagged this vb6-migration but that seems to be for porting code to other languages.